# How to use child component in angular 8?

Tags: angular

```
App
├── ...
└── recruit
    ├── ...
    ├── recruit.module
    └── job
        ├── job.component.html
        ├── ...
        └── component
            ├── ...
            ├── recruitment-child
            └── detail
                ├── ...
                └── recruit-detail-modal
                    ├── ...
                    ├── recruit-detail-modal.component.html
                    └── profile
                        └── profile.component.html
```

I new to Angular and I have a problem.

My app is like this. All I declare in `recruit.module`. With the `recruitment-child` in `job.component.html`. I call it normally.

```
<div *ngFor="let recruitment of recruitments">
   <app-recruitment-child [recruitment]="recruitment"></app-recruitment-child>
</div>
```

But I cant call `profile.component.html` in `recruit-detail-modal.component.html`.

```
<nz-tab>
   <recruit-detail-profile></recruit-detail-profile>
</nz-tab>
```

It notice that:

> 'recruit-detail-profile' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'recruit-detail-profile' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'recruit-detail-profile' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

I think I should add a module in `recruit-detail-modal` and declare `recruit-detail-profile` component

But how should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export the component inside your Module

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [RecruitDetailProfile],
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    exports: [RecruitDetailProfile]
})
```

Comment: it does not work in `recruit.module` but I export in app's module, it runs. tks